# Would it be possible to write a RewriteCond to accomplish this differently

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this rewrite cond:

```
RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(css|js|php|html|png|jpg|gif)|notes|messages|/delete/|/achors_data/|/composer/|/pagination/|/mom_mp3/|/swf/|/js/|/stories/|/wall/|/news_feed/|/notifications/|opencv|hdflvplayer|hdflvplayer2|videojs|ffmpeg|mediaplayer|uploadify|/v/|/video/|/options/|show_msg_dialogs|facedetector|classes|right_column_modules|functions|maurice|pokes|opticrop|geoip_city|/autocomplete/|chrono|ajax|editprofile|tag|Svetlozar.NET
```

It has to be maintained with each new directory that is created on root as I have a rewrite rule that redirects everything from non existing directories (root/mydirectory/ and root/mydirectory_b/) to root/specialdirectory/ except what's on the condition which is just any existing directory in root which does not need to have the rule of going to specialdirectory applied.

My question is if it would be possible to write the rewritecond or take another approach to accomplish the same, not having to write manually each new directory in the .htaccess that is being created in root.

So this is the rewrite rule with the cond that makes everything (root/anydir/) go to
root/master

```
RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(css|js|php|html|png|jpg|gif)|notes|messages|/delete/|/search/|/buttons/|/achors_data/|/composer/|/pagination/|/mom_mp3/|/swf/|/js/|/stories/|/wall/|/news_feed/|/notifications/|opencv|hdflvplayer|hdflvplayer2|videojs|ffmpeg|mediaplayer|uploadify|/v/|/video/|/options/|show_msg_dialogs|facedetector|classes|right_column_modules|functions|maurice|pokes|opticrop|lists|geoip_city|/autocomplete/|chrono|ajax|editprofile|tag|Svetlozar.NET
RewriteRule   ^([A-Za-z-0-9-_.]+)?$ master/$2
```

Then there is the problem in which the directory friends only outside all of the directories in root should perform a certain action anything/friends goes to anything/view_friends.php

What I would like is to be able to write a RewriteCond that takes in consideration every existing directory in root - a wildcard for that.

So I would end up writing something like the following with no maintenance

```
RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_URI} ! * existing directories - except just one
```

instead of:

```
RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(css|js|php|html|png|jpg|gif)|pokes|opticrop|notes|/delete/|/search/|/buttons/|/achors_data/|/composer/|/pagination/|/mom_mp3/|/swf/|/js/|/stories/|/wall/|/news_feed/|/notifications/|opencv|hdflvplayer|hdflvplayer2|videojs|ffmpeg|mediaplayer|uploadify|/v/|/video/|/options/|show_msg_dialogs|facedetector|classes|right_column_modules|functions|maurice|lists|geoip_city|/autocomplete/|chrono|ajax|editprofile|tag|Svetlozar.NET
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-0-9-_.]+)/friends $1/view_friends.php
```

directories must exist as real directories for the rewritecond to apply as I use phantom directories for the first rewriterule.

Comment: Can you show the other existing rules for the redirection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not following what you want exactly. Would easier if you could post the entire htaccess instead of just fragments. Also giving some sample urls would help.

But I'll just go tell you what I use.

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/(.*))?$ - [L]
```

This rule get the first past of the url, before the first `/`, and check if there is an existing directory (in the root) with that name. If so, it will stop processing any  rewrite-rules below it (that's what the `- [L]` part does).